# Why am I getting an error of Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer

I am creating a MERN app, I am new to this. I tried following some tutorials on the net but I have encountered some error.

I am submitting the post request like this. As you can see I am not specifying the content type because I know that if you are using the 'multipart/form-data it will automatically append it to the headers. I am using a react hook here which is why I am not directly using the fetch method.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("email", formState.inputs.email.value);
formData.append("name", formState.inputs.name.value);
formData.append("password", formState.inputs.password.value);
formData.append("image", formState.inputs.image.value);
const responseData = await sendRequest(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL}/api/users/signup`,
    "POST",
    formData
    );
```

meanwhile my signup route is like this, **UNDER user-routes.js**

```
router.post(
  "/signup",
  fileUpload.single("image"),
  [
    check("name").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email")
      .normalizeEmail() // Test@test.com => test@test.com
      .isEmail(),
    check("password").isLength({ min: 6 }),
  ],
  usersController.signup
);
```

as you can also see, I am catching it in the route by using the `fileUpload.single("image")`

if you need to see my hook that I am using here it is, but I am pretty sure that the hook works fine. and it has no issues whatsoever, so here it is: **this is a react hook**

```
export const useHttpClient = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const activeHttpRequests = useRef([]);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (url, method = "GET", body = null, headers = {}) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const httpAbortCtrl = new AbortController();
      activeHttpRequests.current.push(httpAbortCtrl);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
          body,
          headers,
          signal: httpAbortCtrl.signal,
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();

        // console.log("Response: ", response);
        // console.log("Data: ", responseData);

        activeHttpRequests.current = activeHttpRequests.current.filter(
          (reqCtrl) => reqCtrl !== httpAbortCtrl
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(responseData.message);
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
        return responseData;
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
        throw err;
      }
    },
    []
  );

  const clearError = () => {
    setError(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      activeHttpRequests.current.forEach((abortCtrl) => abortCtrl.abort());
    };
  }, []);

  return { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError };
};
```

I will include the signup here from my **users.controller**:

```
const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(
      new HttpError("Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.", 422)
    );
  }

  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  let existingUser;
  try {
    existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Signing up failed, please try again later.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if (existingUser) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "User exists already, please login instead.",
      422
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  let hashedPassword;
  try {
    hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Could not create user, please try again.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  //res.json({ message: "AFTER HASHING" });

  const createdUser = new User({
    name,
    email,
    image: req.file.path,
    password: hashedPassword,
    places: [],
  });

  try {
    await createdUser.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Signing up failed, please try again later.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  let token;
  try {
    token = jwt.sign(
      { userId: createdUser.id, email: createdUser.email },
      process.env.JWT_KEY,
      { expiresIn: "1h" }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Signing up failed, please try again later.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res
    .status(201)
    .json({ userId: createdUser.id, email: createdUser.email, token: token });
};
```

Comment: You are actually returning HTML instead of JSON. You must have received an HTTP error e.g. 404. The result of `const response` after waiting for the promise to resolve, is not a JSON string. So this is failing... `const responseData = await response.json();`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl no I am not returning any html, I have read from here that this will be encountered if you are sending a content-type of 'multiform' while the data that you submitted are json object, here is the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432928/error-in-multer-image-upload-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-syntaxer?fbclid=IwAR3sIulvWZ8xiISuy8onCCxNwhlh_tx6EMRKKY9GCVIO5WFaH1C8eUL7DBQ

Comment: @IvanApungan there's a very easy way to find out: look at the actual HTTP response body in the browser developer tools (the "Network" tab).  Note that as Mr Polywhirl said, your server can return HTML-formatted errors whether your code returns HTML or not.

Comment: @Pointy yes he is correct, it seems that the server is returning an html or text type, but I don't where in the signup route it went wrong, I am assuming the issue is with multer. I am using multer for the uploaded files

Comment: @Pointy it seems that the server that I deployed is returning a internal server error status code of 500, I have used try catch in every scenario for my signup function, but the error is in it. I think the error happens even before it went inside the signup block, maybe its in the fileupload.js file that I am importing in the user-routes.js

Comment: Right, 500 means it's an unexpected server exception of some kind.\

Comment: @Pointy I tried returning a json data right on the bat in the first line inside the signup route, but still the same error so I think the issue is with the file-upload that I am using with multer

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `JSON.Parse()` around your responseData

When ever I run into this bug it is because I either,

- parsed an already parsed object
- Stingified a string
- Used a string as an object

This [link](https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/) goes into more depth about the bug and common ways of dissecting the issue.

Try console.log() in your hook before you send the data and also log what the responseData looks like after it retrieves the data

Comment: If `response.json()` is throwing the syntax error, then it's doing so because it's already passing the response body to `JSON.parse()`.